# Opening different XLS spreadsheets as table with ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, csv, excel, pandas

I am trying to write a Python script that uses a xls file with different spreadsheets as input to build features and  domains  in a geodatabase.

This is the data in Sheet1:

[image]

and this the data in Sheet2

[image]

and I would like to use this as input for making  features in a geodatabase. Below my script is displayed, but it returns the following error:

> string indices must be integers

```
#---Import modules---# 
    import pandas as pd
    import arcpy
    import xlrd

#---Set paths---#  
    SheetFeatureclass = pd.read_excel(r"C:\xlmtofeature\sheets.xls", sheet_name='Sheet1')
    SheetDomain = pd.read_excel(r"C:\xlmtofeature\sheets.xls", sheet_name='Sheet2')
    projection = r'C:\xlmtofeature\RD New.prj'
    out_path = r'C:\xlmtofeature\test.gdb'

#---Colums in Sheet1---#  
    FEATURENAME = SheetFeatureclass['FEATURENAME']
    GEO_TYPE = SheetFeatureclass['GEO_TYPE']

#---Colums in Sheet2---# 
    DOMEIN = SheetDomain ['DOMEIN']
    FIELDTYPE = SheetDomain['FIELDTYPE']
    DOMEINTYPE = SheetDomain ['DOMEINTYPE']

#---Create features ---#
    for row in SheetFeatureclass:
        try:
            arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(out_path, row[FEATURENAME], row[GEO_TYPE], "", "", "",projectie,"","","", "")
            print str(row[FEATURENAME]+ " Toegevoegd" )
        except Exception as err:
            print(err.args[0])
    print "Done with adding features"

#--- create Doamins ---#
    for row in SheetDomain:
        try:
            arcpy.CreateDomain_management(out_path, row[DOMEIN],"",row[FIELDTYPE],row[DOMEINTYPE],"","",)
            print str("Add "+ row[DOMEIN])
        except Exception as err:
            print(err.args[0])
    print "Done with adding Domains"
```

Comment: Try using `sheetname` instead of `sheet_name`.

Comment: Use Make Table View

Answer (score 1):

I find that the easiest way to work with Excel spreadsheets and ArcPy is to use the [Excel To Table](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/conversion/excel-to-table.htm) tool which:

> Converts Microsoft Excel files into a table.

Once you have a table you have the flexibility to work with it using ArcPy cursors.

The syntax of the Excel To Table tool:

```
ExcelToTable_conversion (Input_Excel_File, Output_Table, {Sheet})
```

includes an optional third parameter to allow you to specify a particular worksheet within your spreadsheet.

Once you have your domain table (from the spreadsheet) you can convert it to a geodatabase domain using the [Table To Domain](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/table-to-domain.htm) tool which:

> Creates or updates a coded value domain with values from a table.